# OpenCV Java performing Arithmetic actions on a Mat

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am converting some c++ opencv code into java for a new project. The c++ code looks like this:

```
cv::Mat RGB_img = cv::Mat(someMat.rows, someMat.cols, CV_8UC3);
cv::Mat R_channel = 255-someMat;
cv::Mat B_channel = cv::Mat::zeros(someMat.rows, someMat.cols, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat G_channel = cv::Mat::zeros(someMat.rows, someMat.cols, CV_8UC1);
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels2;
channels2.push_back(B_channel);
channels2.push_back(G_channel);
channels2.push_back(R_channel);
cv::merge(channels2, RGB_img);
```

The same code but converted into java is

```
Mat RGB_img = new Mat(someMat.rows(), someMat.cols(), CV_8UC3);
Mat R_channel = 255 - someMat;
Mat B_channel = Mat.zeros(someMat.rows(), someMat.cols(), CV_8UC1);
Mat G_channel = Mat.zeros(someMat.rows(), someMat.cols(), CV_8UC1);
List<Mat> channels2 = new ArrayList<>();
channels2.add(B_channel);
channels2.add(G_channel);
channels2.add(R_channel);
merge(channels2, RGB_img);
```

The all of the java code compiles just fine apart from this line:

```
Mat R_channel = 255 - someMat;
```

I did some googling on how to perform arithmetic actions on a Mat but I couldn't find anything. There are the functions on Core for add/subtract etc but they take Mats or Scalars.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do this would be grand.

Comment: The `255` would be a Scalar in that case and you'd use the subtract function.

Comment: So like this?         Core.subtract(someMat, new Scalar(255), R_channel);